# Making second parameter optional based on specific value of a key type

Tags: typescript

I have code like

```
interface MY_TYPES {
  'xyz': string;
  'abc': number;
  'baz': undefined;
}

function testIt<T extends keyof MY_TYPES>(key: T, value?: MY_TYPES[T]) {
  console.log(key);

  if (value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

testIt('xyz', 123); // error
testIt('xyz'); // NO ERROR BY TS, but it should show error
testIt('xyz', 'str'); // good
testIt('baz'); // good
testIt('baz', 3); // error
```

In case of `testIt('xyz')` Its showing no error, but I want TS to complain on such cases as MY_TYPES has some value for this key.
But TS is complaining here. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE0D6AVdAFAUQGVkBvAKGWQHIAPATwC9qAuZAZzClAHMBuSjTgAjBK2QgArgFth0AVWrC4zNpJAATCDFAQNAgL7lyMdQjDAA9iGSROASTAAebMgi1Im9sgDWEepYwaFi4hEQAfAAUfvRs2AA0yABucAA2khAA-GwYOPjEANrYALoAlGSCCNbslqkQAHSpljzR-qUCgsBBkSnpEOUUVFRVIDV1jc09aRntgkZG5HZgjpF0TNSJAIwATADM7cgA9IduUFCWUIsQDmCrDMyJ1JxQ1AfHyFVnEOZXN6vKzDeJ0%20UG%20YF%20y1uShUG2Q%20z4RxO0HOlyAA)

Comment: You can give any datatype in your interface like  interface MY_TYPES {
  'xyz': any;
  'abc': any;
  'baz': any | undefined;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and conditionally type the parameter tuple:

```
interface MY_TYPES {
  'xyz': string;
  'abc': number;
  'baz': undefined;
}

function testIt<T extends keyof MY_TYPES>(
  ...args: MY_TYPES[T] extends undefined ? [T] : [T, MY_TYPES[T]]
) {
  const [key, value] = args;
  
  console.log(key);

  if (value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

testIt('xyz'); // error
testIt('xyz', 123); // error
testIt('xyz', 'str'); // correct
testIt('baz'); // correct
testIt('baz', 3); // error
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add [function overloading](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-function-overloading/) to give possible types:

```
interface MY_TYPES {
  'xyz': string;
  'abc': number;
  'baz': undefined;
}
function testIt(key: 'xyz', value: string) : undefined
function testIt(key: 'abc', value: number) : undefined
function testIt(key: 'baz') : undefined


function testIt<T extends keyof MY_TYPES>(key: T, value?: MY_TYPES[T]) {
  console.log(key);

  if (value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

testIt('xyz', 123); // error
testIt('xyz');
testIt('xyz', 'str'); // correct
testIt('baz'); // correct
testIt('baz', 3); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE0D6AVdAFAUQGVkBvAKGWQHIAPATwC9qAuZAZzClAHMBuSjTgAjBK2QgArgFth0AVWrC4zNpJAATCDFAQNAgL7kY6hGGAB7EMkicAkmAAUAawj02dJtQA0yAG5wADaSEGyc3CA8AJTIaprauhrGpuZWNhD2Tq7uQqI+-kEhbFKy0DFxWjogeskgZpbWtmAOLm4eyszlyOqVieT9JnWpjRnNYAA82MgQtJCa7MjZFjBoWLiERAB8rTnYvgHBEAD8bBg4+MQA2tgAujEUVAhW7BaBEAB0gRY8O1ECgsAVo4DiF7oJHs9Xh8vj8QRA-oIjEZyE0Wp5mL4AIwAJgAzH9kAB6QnTKBQCxQFGjNEMToCVFOdH5ajhagE4nIJ5kiBmKmZRxKFRsvhEklcqA8sB8sYCjr5fEijnQcmUoA)